# Internal links in epublib on Android aren't working

Tags: android, epub, epublib

I'm using the [epublib Android library](https://github.com/psiegman/epublib) to read an existing EPUB, and I can't get internal links to work.

One of the chapters has HTML like this

```
<a href="9781484702181.html">Click here</a>
```

but when you actually click on it, you get an Android webview error:

```
The webpage at file:///data/data/com.temp.package/library/epub/9_epub_files/9781484702181.xhtml could not be loaded.
```

I've tried changing the URL like this but neither works.

```
<a href="./9781484702181.html">Click here</a>
<a href="OEPBS/9781484702181.html">Click here</a>
```

Is there anything I need to do in particular to get internal links to work?